# Invoking "cmd.exe" and change "cd" to directory on mapped drive from C# app

Tags: c#, cmd

1. VS_2010 is development tool.
2. I'm developing C# app that need to do the following:
   2a. Invoke "cmd.exe"
   2b. Change directory.
   2c. Start "someApp.exe".

I know how to do 2a.
I know how to do 2b.
I know how to do 2c.

I do NOT know how to do 2b when I need to change directory to one located on network ( Mapped Drive  Y::\aaaa\bbbb\cccc).

Could anybody help ?

thanks

Comment: Why do you launch a program through `cmd.exe`, and not through `Process.Start()`? And if you must do the former, please show your current code.

Comment: You have to do some edit in the registry:

Reference: http://superuser.com/questions/690287/command-prompt-in-administrator-mode-doesnt-see-mapped-drives

Comment: You don't have to edit the registry; the referenced question is for a different situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change directory to a mapped drive. What you *can* do is just set the working directory to that drive in a [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object. If 2a is just a means to an end, this will solve your problem:

```
var proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "someApp.exe";
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"Y:\aaaa\bbbb\cccc";
proc.Start();
```